# How to set kiali-ui/package.json 'proxy' attribute when "yarn start" in kiali-ui?

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, istio, kiali

When I entered `kubectl get pods -A -o wide`, I got this.

```
NAMESPACE   NAME             READY STATUS  .. IP            NODE
kube-system kube-proxy-h1234 1/1   Running .. 203.253.11.11 slave-node2
```

So I edited `/kiali/kiali-ui/config.yaml`

```
{
  "name": "@kiali/kiali-ui",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "proxy": "http://203.253.11.11",
  "description": "React UI for [Kiali](https://github.com/kiali/kiali).",
  "keywords": [
    "istio service mesh",
    "kiali",
    "monitoring",
    "observability",
    "okd",
    "openshift"
  ],
  ...
}
```

And I enter `curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:3000/api`. 
But I got error.

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/auth/info from localhost:3000 to http://203.253.11.11`
```

I think, we should put the IP address of kube-proxy in front of node(kiali service is up on this node) in the `proxy` setting. But it doesn't work.

What address should I put in `proxy` setting?

I refer to this document -> [a link](https://github.com/kiali/kiali-ui)

Comment: Hi @Yong , you should set as proxy the same URL that you use to access kiali from your host / browser. So it depends on your setup (if you use port-forward, ingress, etc.). I'm not sure if you can use kube-proxy somehow here.

Comment: @Joel Thank you. I want to ask one more question about kiali-ui. do you know how to develope kiali-ui in local setting?

Comment: What do you mean by local setting? I'm one of the developers of Kiali, and this is how we do: setting "proxy" in package.json, then running "yarn start". Is there anything wrong about that for you? The backend needs to be accessible in a kubernetes cluster

Comment: @Joel So I installed 'kiali' and 'kiali-ui' locally. I am trying to modify 'kiali-ui'. So, I build kiali-ui through 'yarn build', and I created a docker image file in the kiali folder. I uploaded the generated image to Pod and confirmed the kiali-ui changes.

Comment: However, I feel that this process is cumbersome... 
Is there a way to immediately check for changes without going through this process? Like web development?

Comment: setting 'proxy' and 'yarn start' works. But I can't access kiali web page. I want to check changes that i fixed..

Comment: If you have only frontend changes, you shouldn't have to fetch and rebuild kiali (backend), just kiali-ui. However, one reason why it might not work is if you're running an outdated kiali backend with latest frontend

Comment: To avoid backend/frontend version mismatch I recommend you develop from a recent tag/version. For example, having v1.1.0 running and from kiali UI you can create a branch from that tag

Comment: PS: you can chat on IRC / freenode, #kiali , if it's easier for you. There's always some devs there. I'm "jotak" there.